# Oracle "direct path read" Average wait time in AWR

Tags: database, oracle, performance, io, awr

I have a top wait event of "direct path read", which shows Average Wait time (Avg wait (ms)) of 96ms (in the top 5 events section). 
However, in the "Tablespace IO Stats" section, the only active tablespace (USERS) shows that "Av Rd(ms)" is at 2ms. 
How could this be? Bug in the AWR report? - Or does Oracle somehow calculate the average wait for direct path reads in a different manner? - Anything else I should be looking at?

Top 5 Timed Foreground Events

```
Event   Waits   Time(s) Avg wait (ms)   % DB time   Wait Class
direct path read    64,753  6,219   96  72.51   User I/O

Tablespace IO Stats
ordered by IOs (Reads + Writes) desc
Tablespace  Reads   Av Reads/s  Av Rd(ms)   Av Blks/Rd  Writes  Av Writes/s Buffer Waits    Av Buf Wt(ms)
USERS   234,653 61  1.59    61.38   94,687  25  12  20.83
UNDOTBS1    307 0   1.30    1.00    208,752 54  0   0.00
TEMP    10,279  3   0.10    14.99   10,276  3   0   0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance in the documentation shows that this wait might be misleading, as some I/O events are asynchronous. You can read more about it here -
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16240_01/doc/doc.102/e16282/oracle_database_help/oracle_database_wait_bottlenecks_direct_path_read_pct.html